# How to share gentoo folder (as guest host) with the host os (windows 7) in Virtual Box

Tags: linux, windows-7, virtualbox, gentoo

I have windows 7 as host os and i'm running gentoo os as guest inside virtual box. I want a folder in the guest os to be shared with host os.

The folder already exists in the guest os and has files in it therefore I can not go for the option of creating a folder in the host os and sharing that instead.

Any help is much appreciated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtualbox guest utilities can only share directories in one direction: host to guest.

The recommendation on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/241825/share-virtualbox-folders-in-reverse-guest-host) is to use Samba to share directories from the guest back to the host. All traffic will go over the virtual network, so it will have very low overhead.