# VirtualBox - sharing folders between the host and the guest (Host: Win 8.1, Guest: Win XP)

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox, windows-8.1, shared-folders

I want to get a direct access from my host to my guest machine. I'm using windows 8.1 as a host, and windows xp as a guest (virtual box).

With the "Guest Addition" feature, I have access from guest to host, but I need it in reverse - host to guest.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Virtualbox does not provide a mechanism for doing this, for several reasons. Try using network intermediaries like MS File/Print Sharing, RDP/VNC, psexec, etc instead. between them, you can access every feature and resource of the guest as though you were on it.

Comment: Thank you Frank. I just wonder, is it possible with VMware?

Comment: No, no modern virtualization platform will give the host direct access to the guest's resources, because it violates one of the most fundemental principals of systems virtualization; isolation. What type of resource on the guest do you want to access?

Comment: I'm using the guest as a Linux web server (for now just local, with xampp), because, for a server, Win8.1 is slow as hell. So, I need a direct access to my htdocs files.
Which of the network intermediaries you've listed you suggest?

Comment: if you want to access files hosted on the guest, the easiest method is to install openssh-server on the guest and use winscp on the host to connect and access files. or you could use Samba to share the files and access them via MS file sharing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Share VirtualBox folders in reverse? Guest-Host?](https://superuser.com/questions/241825/share-virtualbox-folders-in-reverse-guest-host)

Answer (score -1):

There are many way to do this! Which way is better for you, depend only on your liking. For a few examples, you can use:

1. Windwos built-in "stuff"
2. NFS
3. Samba
4. SSH
5. Dropbox with LANsync enabled
6. Various 3rd party solutions, like [ShareMouse](http://www.keyboard-and-mouse-sharing.com/index.html) and [Synergy](http://synergy-project.org/)
7. Change hidden VB settings (read the manual) to share whole or part of host physical disk.