# Share a VirtualBox guest machine folder with host machine

Tags: virtualbox, windows-8.1, network-shares, file-sharing

My question is simular to this [question](https://superuser.com/q/241825/109803).
Since the question was asked years ago, virtualbox development has changed owners.

In my case I have windows 8.1 running a windows 8.1 vm. Is there a way to share guest folders with the host machine *using any of the features of windows 8* or the latest version of Virtual Box (4.3.22)?

Comment: Related: [Mount a guest directory on host](https://superuser.com/q/1186176/87805).