# Share folder from Windows Guest OS to Ubuntu Host OS

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, virtualbox

I have Windows 10 (Guest OS) installed using VirtualBox in Ubuntu 16.04 (Host OS). I am trying to use the Google Drive Windows software to be able to sync Google Drive with my computer, by installing it in the VM and then sharing that folder with Ubuntu.

Although I've been able to install and sync Google Drive in my VM, now I can't find the way to see that folder in Ubuntu, since I am trying to share a folder from Guest to Host. Is there any way of doing this???

I've tried to sync Google Drive into a shared folder (from Host to Guest) with no success. Any suggestion??

Thanks!!!

Comment: I face the same issue with OneDrive.

Comment: Have you thought about trying to use WINE for this?  Looks like it can be done.  https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/6ytiil/running_google_backup_and_sync_via_wine/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Share VirtualBox folders in reverse? Guest-Host?](https://superuser.com/questions/241825/share-virtualbox-folders-in-reverse-guest-host)

Answer (score 1):

VirtualBox has this ability built into it's VirtualBox Additions.
See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/SharedFolders

Before sharing folders, you must install Guest Additions. For instructions on how to do this, see Guest Additions (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/GuestAdditions).

**Creating a shared folder**

- Create a folder on the Host computer (ubuntu) that you would like to
  share, for example ~/share
- Boot the Guest operating system in VirtualBox.
- Select Devices -> Shared Folders...
- Choose the 'Add' button. Select ~/share
- Optionally select the 'Make permanent' option

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. This only works for folders in the Host computer. The problem is that the Google Drive software syncs in a Guest computer folder, and that is why I need to share a guest folder with the host computer (there is no google drive software for Linux).